# apk with no lib and no .so file its not 64 bit support

Tags: java, android, 64-bit

I created a sample app base in mediaplayer and images after compiling the apk and doing the analyze apk there is no lib file or (.so) file which means the app supports 64 bit, but when I upload the apk to Google Play it say that it does not support 64 bit.

Did any one have this problem before?

[image: Analyze Apk screen]